# Query two tables to obtain list with most recent date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2.  One table is a lookup table that holds a Service description and the other table holds service history for a client.  I need to write a query to list all of the service types and when they were last used.  Here are the fields in the two tables that I need to work with:

```
Table1: Code_Service
ULink
Description

Table2: Service_History
ServiceTypeULink
RecordUpdateDateTime

Table1 data:
ULink                                       Description
037dc811-4d56-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXc          Dental
5589e876-9c48-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXd          Surgical Procedure
177rt522-2s96-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXa          Specialty

Table2 data:
ServiceTypeULink                            RecordUpdateDateTime
037dc811-4d56-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXc          10/11/2014 12:38:02 PM
5589e876-9c48-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXd          4/21/2013 10:45:28 AM
177rt522-2s96-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXa          11/22/2015 11:37:35 AM
```

The ULink and ServiceTypeULink fields are what relates them.  So, I need to query for all the "Code_Service.Description" used in Service_History which have the most recent "RecordUpdateDateTime".  I wrote the following query and it seems to work, but not sure if this is correct (or a better/faster) way to do it considering I'm on SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT
  Code_Service.Description
 ,MAX(Service_History.RecordUpdatedDateTime) AS DateLastUsed
FROM dbo.Service_History
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Code_Service
  ON Service_History.ServiceTypeULink = Code_Service.ULink
GROUP BY Code_Service.Description
ORDER BY DateLastUsed DESC
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do it, but if you need any more info from either table, you can also use:

```
with MyCTE as
(
SELECT
  Code_Service.Description
 ,Service_History.RecordUpdatedDateTime
 -- add any other columns needed in here --
 ,row_number() over (partition by ServiceTypeULink 
                     order by RecordUpdatedDateTime desc) as R_ORD
FROM dbo.Service_History
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Code_Service
  ON Service_History.ServiceTypeULink = Code_Service.ULink
)
select *
from MyCTE
where R_ORD = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much John!  I like how you used a Common Table Expression (CTE) and then queried on that where the row_number = 1.  Learned something today.  Thanks again.